# Solr - IO Exception while posting data: java.net.ConnectionException

Tags: hadoop, solr, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am trying use apache solr to index data on clouera in Hadoop using cloudera's CDH 4.7

```
$ java -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update -jar post.jar monitor.xml" throws an error 
"SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8993/solr/collection1/update using content-type application/xml..
POSTing file monitor.xml
SimplePostTool: FATAL: IOException while posting data: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"
```

I ensured that all the other settings have been performed correctly.
I went through the blogs posted for this but couldn't still figure out why the connection is getting refused. The solr service in cloudera manager is running on port 8983.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to go with Cloudera CDH 5.2 which has already resolved this issue. The SOLR folder is missing in /user/share/docs and you have to explicitly put the solr files inside.